# How can I get touched up paint to match?

Tags: paint

I recently tried to touch up a spot on my living room wall.  Nearly 20 hours later, that spot looks exactly like it did when I first painted it.  I have the exact paint that the wall was painted with.  Should I water down the paint a little to help it match?  Would painting again with the watered down solution even help?  I absolutely cannot repaint the whole wall, but hope there is a way to fix this.  Will rolling over this spot with a roller brush instead of a regular paint brush make a difference?

Comment: I want to add that I'm 100% positive the texture difference is making the new spot stick out, since the look and feel of the rest of the wall is different.

Comment: Please describe what the spot is and what you did to cover it up. Some spots will bleed through paint no matter how many coats you put on.  You say texture, are you talking about the paint being a different texture or the wall itself is textured but the spot has a different texture?

Answer (score 6):

The texture difference is most likely the function of brush vs. roller. Do not thin the paint. Try using a roller, but use very litle paint on it. You are trying to get just a bit of a top coat that give the slight stippling that vitually all rollers leave behind.

Answer (score 4):

Paint takes 30 days to cure - it will gradually change in its appearance as it does so.

So - best thing to do right now is wait.

Comment: wow - this could explain why the spot on the top of my touch-up can doesn't match the spot I painted 4 days ago.